# unable to use React-Native-Tts giving error Native module cannot be loaded

Tags: react-native, expo

I simply created a react-native-project using expo and added react-native-tts and tried to use the speak function but it is giving Native module cannot be null.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Tts from 'react-native-tts';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        onPress = {() => {Tts.speak("Hello, world!")}}
        title = "voice"
        />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Did you run react-native run-android again?

Answer (score 1):

This is an expo project and react-native-tts is not made for expo. So for text to speech I need to use expo-speech or eject the project from expo.